# Sum of ranks in a binary tree - is there a better way

Tags: math, tree, big-o, time-complexity, abstract-data-type

Maybe this question does not belong as this is not a programming question per se, and i do apologize if this is the case.

I just had an exam in abstract data structures, and there was this question:

the rank of a tree node is defined like this: if you are the root of the tree, your rank is 0. Otherwise, your rank is the rank of your parents + 1.

Design an algorithm that calculates the sum of the ranks of all nodes in a binary tree. What is the runtime of your algorithm?

My answer I believe solves this question, my psuedo-code is as such:

```
int sum_of_tree_ranks(tree node x)
{
    if x is a leaf return rank(x)
    else, return sum_of_tree_ranks(x->left_child)+sum_of_tree_ranks(x->right_child)+rank(x)
}
```

where the function rank is

```
int rank(tree node x)
{
    if x->parent=null return 0
    else return 1+rank(x->parent)
}
```

it's very simple, the sum of ranks of a tree is the sum of the left subtree+sum of the right subtree + rank of the root.

The runtime of this algorithm I believe is `n^2`. i believe this is the case because we were not given the binary tree is balanced. it could be that there are `n` numbers in the tree but also `n` different "levels", as in, the tree looks like a linked list rather than a tree. so to calculate the rank of a leaf, potentially we go n steps up. the father of the leaf will be n-1 steps up etc...so thats `n+(n-1)+(n-2)+...+1+0=O(n^2)`

My question is, is this correct? does my algorithm solve the problem? is my analysis of the runtime correct? and most importantly, is there a better solution to solve this, that does not run in `n^2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm works. your analysis is correct. The problem can be solved in O(n) time: (take care of leaves by yourself)

```
int rank(tree node x, int r)
{
    if x is a leaf return r
    else
        return rank(x->left_child, r + 1)+ ranks(x->right_child, r + 1) + r
}
rank(tree->root, 0)
```

Comment: what is r in this case?

Comment: last line: start with the root and r being 0.

Answer (score 1):

It can be solved in `O(n)` time where `n is number of Nodes` in Binary tree .
It's nothing but sum of height of all nodes where height of root node is zero . 
As

Algorithm:
    Input binary tree with left and right child 
    sum=0;
    output sum

```
PrintSumOfrank(root,sum):
if(root==NULL) return 0;
return PrintSumOfrank(root->lchild,sum+1)+PrintSumOfRank(root->Rchild,sum+1)+sum;
```

**Edit:**
This can be also solved using queue or level order of traversal tree.
Algorithm using Queue:

```
int sum=0;
int currentHeight=0;
Node *T;
Node *t1;
if(T!=NULL)
enque(T);
while(Q is not empty) begin
currentHeight:currentHeight+1 ;
for each nodes in Q do 
  t1 = deque();
 if(t1->lchild!=NULL)begin
   enque(t1->lchild);sum = sum+currentHeight; 
 end if
 if(t1->rchild!=NULL)begin
   enque(t1->rchild);sum = sum+currentHeight; 
 end if
end for 
end while 
print sum ;
```

Comment: something is odd, because at the title, your function gets 1 parameter, but then you call it again with 2 parameters. but i understand your way of thinking

Answer (score 1):

You're right but there is an ***O(n)*** solution providing you can use a more "complex" data structure.
Let each node hold its rank and update the ranks whenever you add/remove, that way you can use the O(1) statement:

```
return 1 + node->left.rank + node->right.rank;
```

and do this for each node on the tree to achieve ***O(n)***.

A thumb rule for reducing Complexity time is: if you can complex the data structure and add features to adapt it to your problem, you can reduce Complexity time to ***O(n)*** most of the times.

Comment: I asked the teacher that exact same question. The nodes do not hold their rank.

Comment: Well in that case you can let the stack hold the ranks for you as @Hamid Alaei suggested